# unable to create sqlite database in Android

Tags: java, android

i have class CreateDB

```
public class CreateDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{   // SQLiteOpenHelper auto create if db not exists.

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.db";

    public CreateDB(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE friends (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, phonenumber INTEGER);");
    }}
```

i call createdb in another class which act as background thread

```
public class manager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 public  Context context;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        CreateDB dbhelp = new CreateDB(context);
}
```

}

when i run it then it stop working and emulator give error that app stop responding

but when i run `CreateDB dbhelp = new CreateDB(this);   in main activity then it works and database is created .  so please help so that i can create database in background thread .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when i run `CreateDB dbhelp = new CreateDB(this);` in main
>   activity then it works and database is created

Because you forgot to initialize your `context` object in your `AsyncTask`.

```
public class manager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 public  Context context; <-- Declared but not initialized

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        CreateDB dbhelp = new CreateDB(context);
}
```

You could create a constructor for your AsyncTask :

```
public manager(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}
```

And then in your activity :

```
new manager(this).execute();
```

Also try to respect name conventions.

Comment: so how can i initialize Context context  and with what

Comment: When you're calling the asynctask in your activity, you can pass the activity itself as argument(with `this`), like I did in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass valid context as a parameter:

```
CreateDB dbhelp = new CreateDB(getContext());
```